# i have no idea about the wrong,please help me

Tags: parameters, resources, boolean

```
i found the Warning:Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/u656351845/public_html/just/activation.php on line 11 Your account could not be activated!
```

my table is ok.
when i run the code,database table value upgrade from 0 to 1 under id. 
but i can not solve Warning.
code is here:`<?php
include_once "DB_connect.php";
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
$id = preg_replace("[^0-9]", "", $id);`

and`$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE loged_in_user SET emailactivated='1' WHERE id='$id'");
$sql_doublecheck=mysql_query("SELECT*FORM loged_in_user WHERE id='$id' AND emailactivated='1' LIMIT 1");
$doublecheck =  mysql_num_rows($sql_doublecheck);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning message is clear here: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

See PHP help for function "mysql_query", it returns FALSE (boolean) if it fails.

And seems to fail because you have incorrect syntax: SELECT*FORM in your second query

You need it to be SELECT * FROM with spaces...

Comment: Thanks boss. i dont use spaces.you r really great.